# Get product collection with an ip range

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to get product collection with an ip range.

I try:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('from' => $start ,'to' => $end))
                        ->load();
```

And works in my local but not in the test server. I need other option, or know if this is the only way to look for another problem.

Answer (score 1):

another option is you can use range by less then and greater than operator.see code below.

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('gteq'=>1))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('lteq'=>100))
```

Comment: It doesn't works, it's still shows 0 products (and i know there are more)

Comment: can you try again now ? i have modified answer

Comment: it works with small numbers, but i'm sure there's products with the range id's i set

Comment: You can check from admin prodct grid by range of ids. to verify number of products.